# Access denied when start, stop or restart iot service on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, services

I installed iot service on Pi. I can get device id and check the device status. As far as I remember I also did not have difficulty in starting and stopping or restarting the service when I first installed it. 
Today however when I was doing other steps of the tutorial I started getting access denied error. 
After a few trials, I removed and reinstalled the service. I also restarted the Pi a few times. Still I have the problem in managing the service. 
The service runs itself (it is activated by OS during startup) My code also do not work it gets authorization related errors so I assumed if I can solve the managing the service I can also fix my some other problems.

I also wonder where can I see logs coming from services in Raspbian?

Thank you for your time and interest and merry Christmas to everybody :)

Ferda

Comment: Maybe it is not related to the servicesI may be somehow changed the security settings of the Raspberry device so my authorization level is not enough to manage the services . Just an assumption..

Answer (score 1):

You can see the logs on `/var/log/`. I think it could be on syslog log.